# How to convert a list to a data-frame in r

Tags: r

Help me please with follow:

I have a list like that:

open   close 
12.15.16  $15  $16
12.16.16  $18  $19

(Index:  Date)

But I need a data-frame like this:

date       open   close 
 12.15.16  $15  $16
 12.16.16  $18  $19

Comment: How do you have a list like that? Can you `dput()` the object so we can see how it's actually structured? This isn't clear from your text representation. See [how to create a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, it looks like the OP have a data.frame with rownames and wanted to have a separate column with rownames.  In that case

```
 df2 <- cbind(date = row.names(df1),df1)
 row.names(df2) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i need